# Check for a character that appears 2 times in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, string, where-clause

I am trying to check if the o appears 2 times in the string and I did it like this, but it doesn't work, is there a mistake in my code?

```sql
SELECT cu.*
FROM Customers cu
WHERE LOWER(cu.FirstName) REGEXP 'o{2}'

-- 'zoom' => correct
-- 'antonio' => correct
-- 'leo jisoo' => fail
```

thank you

Comment: Exactly 2 times or 2 or more times?

Comment: mysql regexp is not case sensitive so LOWER is redundant but otherwise the expression is correct and it works on my system. As for why leo jisoo fails - my guess is that either of the 'o's or both are not actually 'o' but some other character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You code checks for two consecutive `o`s, which is not what you want.

You could write this as:

```
where 
    FirstName like '%o%o%'
    and FirstName not like '%o%o%o%'
```

This checks if the string contains exactly to `o`s.

Another approach is:

```
length(replace(FirstName, 'o', '')) = length(FirstName) - 2
```

Comment: I would like to check if the string has exactly 2 o letters

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT cu* FROM Customers cu WHERE LENGTH(LOWER(cu.FirstName)) - LENGTH(REPLACE(LOWER(cu.FirstName), 'o', '')) = 2;
```